# How to get store from redux-persist on app load in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have a problem running `react-native` app. I've got a store that uses `redux-persist` and some other middleware and the problem is when the app loads, data from the store is not there, only the default values. However as soon as I touch any button the data is there, so the problem is I can't delay rendering until the store is rehydrated. I've tried options with wrapping the app with `PersistGate` with both `loading` and `bootstrapped` values, however this does not work for me. The current code is:

**Store config:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware = [
  promise(),
  thunk,
];

if (__DEV__) { // eslint-disable-line
  // middlewares.push();
}

const enhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; // eslint-disable-line

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(pReducer, {}, enhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**Root Reducer:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loginScreenReducer from 'screens/login/LoginScreen.reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  loginScreenReducer,
});
```

**App:**

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Root from 'Root.component';
import { store, persistor } from 'reduxConfig/store';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          {(bootstrapped) => {
            if (bootstrapped) {
              console.log(store.getState());
              return <Root />;
            }

            return <AppLoading />;
          }}
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**The component I'd like to make work correctly:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Navigator from './Navigator';
import { LoginScreen } from '../screens';

@connect(
  state => ({
    token: state.loginScreenReducer.token,
    isLogged: state.loginScreenReducer.isLogged,
  }),
)
export default class AppNavigator extends Component {
  state = { }

  render() {
    const {
      token,
    } = this.props;

    if (token) {
      return <Navigator />;
    }

    return <LoginScreen />;
  }
}

export const { router } = Navigator;
```

The component shows login screen first but if I touch any button on it, it renders `Navigator` component. Also when I get the state of the store (App, before returning `<Root />`, it has the next structure, containing empty object, which is currently default for `loginScreenReducer`:

[image: Store contents]

The app works correctly except for `redux-persist`.

Answer (score 0):

===== New Answer =====

The old answer is wrong, the problem came back later. It looks like it's a problem with redux-persist, or even expo, react-native-scripts or whatever, I was not been able to locate the problem source. The behavior I described before comes from redux-persist inability to access AsyncStorage. However the only thing that helps now is completely stopping expo and running it again, after that redux-persist is able to access AsyncStorage again.

It also looks like disabling live reload really helps with this problem if not stops it at all.

===== Old Answer =====

I've ended up by downgrading react-redux package to version 4.4.9, looks like this has solved the problem, otherwise the code I posted initially should be totally okay. The problem with auto-filling state on button press was caused my a couple of my own mistakes both from BE and FE sides, that lead to store be filled with different items. They are not in the given code. Also I've changed my store a little, I'm not sure if the initial problem was connected to `enhancers` combining. So now my store looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { LOGOUT } from 'screens/login/LoginScreen.actions';
import appReducer from './reducers';

const middlewares = [
  promiseMiddleware(),
  thunk,
];

if (__DEV__) { // eslint-disable-line
  middlewares.push(createLogger());
}

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
    state = undefined;
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

I hope this will help somebody.